# Cluster analysis based on Jump Method (Distortion Measure)

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means, distortion

I am trying to reproduce the results form the Sugar's paper:

Catherine A. Sugar; Gareth M. James (2003). "Finding the number of clusters in a data set: An information theoretic approach". Journal of the American Statistical Association 98 (January): 750–763

on clustering analysis using the jump method. 
Here is a Link to WiKi-Pedia with the pseudo-code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set.

The code in Matlab is here:

```
load('iris.mat'); % data into X
p = size(X,2);
K = 1:10;
for k=K
  disp(['Clustering with K = ' num2str(k) ' ...']);
  [U, Z] = kmeans(X, k, 'emptyaction', 'singleton');
  % compute distortion
  for i=1:k
    S = cov(X(U==i,:));
    a = bsxfun(@minus, X(U==i,:), Z(i,:));
    b = [b; sum(diag(a*inv(S)*a'))/sum(U==i)];
  end
  % average distortion per attribute
  b = b / p;
  d = [d; mean(b)];
end

figure, plot(K, d, '.:'); title('Distortion');
figure, plot(K(1:end-1), diff(d.^(-p/2)), '.:'); title('Jump Result');
```

Now, the distortion shows a non-uniform decreasing function, and the jump result shows spikes and sometimes a maximum at k=8, or even negative numbers.

I assume I am doing something wrong here. Could anyone help me getting the mistake in the code?

Comment: OK, "issue" found.
1) `cov()` has to be removed, and only summatory of the L2 distances between each point and its center has to be computed.
2) Sum of the total distortion and then averaging by number of samples and dimension, e.g. `sum(dist)/(n*p)`.
3) exponent in the transformation should be less than 1 and p/2 does indeed deliver a higher number of clusters.

Comment: is it possible for you to edit your post and type the new "fixed" algorithm?